# Vuejs unit test components error on $mount()

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, karma-mocha

I'm trying to follow the standard pattern set out by the veujs docs to mount a component in order to access its data during different states via lifecycle hooks, however, any attempt to call the $mount() function after extending the component with the Vue instance triggers a render error and skips assertions in the suite immediately thereafter.

Execute command from package json:

```
"cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run"
```

Spec file setup and mount function call:

```
describe('component.vue', () => {
  let Ctor
  let vm

  beforeEach(() => {
    Ctor = Vue.extend(component)
    vm = new Ctor().$mount()
  })
```

Error trace on npm run unit:

```
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
(found in <Root>)'
ERROR LOG: TypeError{stack: 'render@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:77038:32
_render@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:10690:26
updateComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:9239:28
get@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:9550:29
Watcher@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:9533:15
mountComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:9243:28
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:14333:24
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:16382:20
http://localhost:9876/base/specs/component.spec.js?adb355a285fbdae55582a83df658adee4846d0e1:46421:27
```

karma config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // to run in additional browsers:
    // 1. install corresponding karma launcher
    //    http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/browsers.html
    // 2. add it to the `browsers` array below.
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai'],
    // chai config
    client: {
      chai: {
        includeStack: true
      }
    },
    reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],
    files: [
      '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
      'specs/*.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'specs/*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: './coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: '.' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
      ]
    },
  });
};
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your component as well? error in render could be for different reasons, if your component requires data or uses specific stuff that you are not passing them, it will trigger the error.

Comment: Yes thank you, I found out that my template in the component has reference to $config and commenting that line removes the errors I have when running the test.